# How can I derive the left side of the the identity to be equal to the right?

Tags: calculus, probability, permutations

$$\frac{(n-1)!(-n)_{k-n}}{(k-1)!}=(-1)^{k-n}$$

I've been doing things just to prove this identity but I cannot come up the same result as what's in the right side.

I have no idea about this, can you help me?

that is a falling factorial... i am just confused how can i cancel  $(k-1)!$ in the numerator (after extracting out the $(−1)^{k−n}$ )...so that i cancel it together with the $(k-1)!$ in the denominator
and resulting to $(−1)^{k−n}$ ) only which is already equal to the right side.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried already?

Comment: Is that supposed to be $(-n)^{k-n}$?

Comment: I think $(-n)_{k-n}$ denotes the [falling factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html), so $(-n)_{k-n}=(-n)(-n-1)\cdots(-n-(k-n-1))$. I think he also inexplicitly means $k\geq n$

Comment: yes , that is a falling factorial... i am just confused how can i cancel  $(k-1)!$ in the numerator (after extracting out the $(−1)^{k−n}$ )...so that i cancel it together with the $(k-1)!$ in the denominator
and resulting to $(−1)^{k−n}$ ) only which is already equal to the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{{\pars{n - 1}!\pars{-n}_{k - n} \over \pars{k - 1}!} =
> \pars{-1}^{k - n}:\ {\large ?}}$.

With $\ds{\alpha, \beta \not\in \mathbb{Z}}$:
\begin{align}
{\pars{\alpha - 1}!\pars{-\alpha}_{\beta - \alpha} \over \pars{\beta - 1}!} & =
{\Gamma\pars{\alpha} \over \Gamma\pars{\beta}}\,
{\Gamma\pars{-\alpha + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{-\alpha - \beta + \alpha + 1}} =
{\sin\pars{\pi\beta} \over \sin\pars{\pi\alpha}}
\\[5mm]
\left.\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}{\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{k + \epsilon}} \over \sin\pars{\pi\bracks{n + \epsilon}}}\right\vert_{\ k,n\ \in \mathbb{Z}} & =
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}{\cos\pars{\pi\bracks{k + \epsilon}}\pi \over \cos\pars{\pi\bracks{n + \epsilon}}\pi} =
{\cos\pars{\pi k} \over \cos\pars{\pi n}} = \bbx{\ds{\pars{-1}^{k - n}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The falling factorial is related to the rising factorial

$(x)_r=(-1)^r(-x)^r$

Where ;

$(x)^r= x(x+1)(x+2)......(x+(r-1))=$ [Rising Factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RisingFactorial.html)

$(x)^r= (x+(r-1))......(x+2)(x+1)(x)$    Reversed

$$(x)^r= \frac {(x+(r-1))......(x+2)(x+1)(x)(x-1)(x-2).....3\times2\times1}{(x-1)(x-2).....3\times2\times1}$$

$$(x)^r= \frac {(x+(r-1))...........3\times2\times1}{(x-1).....3\times2\times1}$$

$$ \implies (x)^r= \frac {(x+r-1)!}{(x-1)!}$$

Coming to your question :

$$ \text {L.H.S}=\frac{(n-1)!(-n)_{k-n}}{(k-1)!}$$

$$=\Bigg(\frac{(n-1)!(-1)^{k-n}}{(k-1)!}\Bigg)(n)^{k-n}$$

$$=\Bigg(\frac{(n-1)!(-1)^{k-n}}{(k-1)!}\Bigg)\times \frac {((n)+(k-n)-1)!}{(n-1)!}$$

$$=\frac{(n-1)!(-1)^{k-n}}{(k-1)!}\times \frac {(k-1)!}{(n-1)!}$$

$$\text {L.H.S.}=(-1)^{k-n}= \text {R.H.S.}$$

Comment: hi, i just want to ask if where did you get the denominator $(x-1)!$ in $$(x)^r=\frac{(x+r−1)!}{(x−1)!}$$

Comment: @Raygor See my new edit.I have cleared there.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a life saver. It helps me understand how interesting it is.